# COM IUnknown and do I need a pointer to it first before calling CoGetClassObject?

Tags: object, com, iunknown

In COM, when you want to create an instance of some COM Server object, do you first need to get a pointer to it's IUnknown interface and only then create a class object using CoGetClassObject?

As far as I understand it, IUnknown is used to manage object lifetimes, so from my understanding, whatever object the client wants to create, one needs a pointer to it's IUnknown interface implementation first.

Sound correct?  If not, can anyone tell me how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IUnknown` manages the lifespan of an *existing* COM object. Before the object is created, there is no `IUnknown` pointer to speak of.

`CoGetClassObject` is used to get the `IUnknown` interface for an object that is expected to create the objects of interest. I.e., it is an object *factory*, an usually implements `IClassFactory`, which declares the `CreateInstance` method that you use to create objects.

Instead of using class factories explicitly, it is often simpler to just call `CoCreateInstance`.

Comment: So only object implementing IUnknown can be used in COM by a client?

Comment: Tony: All objects must implement `IUnknown`. This interface is not very useful in its own right, but it declares the `QueryInterface` method, which lets you discover the other interfaces supported by the object.

Comment: `IUnknown` *is* useful on its own since its helps track object lifetime.

Comment: @sharptooth: I didn't say it isn't useful on its own.